# kafka Brokers Leader Skewed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have 10 node kafka cluster .both kafka broker and zookeeper are running on each node. Recently we have added 3 new nodes 8 ,9 and 10  and yesterday 2 node was down (2 and 4). I have a topic with 60 partitions and 3 replication. In kafka manager, `Brokers Skewed %` is showing as 50 and `Brokers Leader Skewed %` as 70. I have manually reassigned the partition from UI and  `Brokers Skewed %` is 0 now but it didn't change `Brokers Leader Skewed %`. I also ran the command:

```
$ kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh  --zookeeper localhost:2181 --path-to-json-file test.json

Warning: --zookeeper is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Kafka.
Use --bootstrap-server instead to specify a broker to connect to.
Created preferred replica election path with ...
Successfully started preferred replica election for partitions Set(..
```

but it didn't change anything. I can see on UI that brokers 8 and 10 have no leader. How can I rebalance leaders across all brokers evenly? I read that cluster rolling restart of all broker can solve it but I can't (in normal case) restart my production Kafka cluster.

```
kafka version: 2.3.0
zookeeper version: 3.4.12
```

added kafka manager screenshot and highlighted the issue with the red circle.

[image: kafka manager]

[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. if you will see the screenshots carefully, you will notice that none of the preferred replica (first entry of `Replicas` column) is assigned to broker 8 or 10 and only parition 37 has broker 9 as preferred replica so `Preferred Replica Election` will not work.

I have shuffled preferred replicas using `Manual Partition Assignments` (moving broker 8,9 and 10 to replica 0 in 17 paritions (6*3 -2)) option and then running `Reassign Partitions` and then running `Preferred Replica Election`.

I hope it will behelpful to others.

**Note:** 8,9 and 10 node was added recently.